# Google form doesn't load in iframe in html

Tags: html, iframe, web

I'm using `<iframe>` in HTML5 which is working correctly for all other links except google forms. Please tell me where I am wrong. Here is the link where I'm using:
http://www.sciencekidunya.com/event

and the google form link is:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1ehENKS61N8rmXHxvIk7A8l0ocKBTpjgN4zpY-VDqJXs/viewform

and the code is:

```
 <body>
 <center><img src="banner.jpg" width="100%" height="40%"><br><br>
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1ehENKS61N8rmXHxvIk7A8l0ocKBTpjgN4zpY-VDqJXs/viewform"></iframe>
 </center></body>
```

Comment: Error: The server refused the connection.

Comment: This is because "Load denied by X-Frame-Options". Currenty in Chrome browser  you can see your form. So you need to make X-Frame-Options: allow option to make it visible on all browsers.

Answer (score 4):

In some cases, the form may not be visible to other people until you change its visibility settings.

To do that:

1. Go to the "Settings" tab.
2. Click the dropdown arrow to the right of "Responses".
3. Uncheck the "Restrict to users in (your organization) and its trusted organizations" checkbox.

Your iframe should now load correctly.